# How to submit spark job from within java program to standalone spark cluster without using spark-submit?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using spark to perform some computations but want it to be submitted from java application.It works proper using when submitted using spark-submit script.Has anyone tried to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget to add the fat JAR containing your code to the context.

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
   .setMaster(...)
   .setAppName(...)
   .setJars("/path/to/code.jar")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have a master and available worker started, you should be able to if you have the following in your java application:

```
String master = "spark://IP:7077"; //set IP address to that of your master
String appName = "Name of your Application Here";
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master);;
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

I was able to run junit tests from within IntelliJ that utilized the JavaSparkContext without having to use the spark-submit script. I am running into issues when performing actions on DataFrames though (not sure if that's related).

Comment: I have done the same thing but no luck.If I ran it using spark-submit then it works perfect.Have you tried to perform some transformations? @insomniak

Comment: For me it worked when providing these options:  -Dspark.driver.host=<my ip> -Dspark.driver.port=50000

Comment: Can I please have a java code to run an spark application.

Comment: I solved this problem with answer provided by @Marius Soutier